# Thinner Android SwitchCompat

Tags: android, switchcompat

I am trying to achieve this using a SwitchCompat:

[image: thinner SwitchCompat]

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: You are asking with custom images or without? Because in your image there is no custom image.

Comment: Actually I could use either ...

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Material design then you have to set your accent color that is handling color or your controls:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

And if you want only for particular view then create a new style and add this items (colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated,colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal) with colors like above code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have problems with the thin background line. Default SwitchCompat has a thicker line. I think this items are only for the colors, not for the background line.